# Can I disable TCP windows scaling for a single application?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

In Linux, can an application enable or disable [TCP window scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option#Linux) for TCP/IP connections created by the application? As opposed to a system-wide modification through `sysctl` using the `net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling` parameter.

Comment: Why? Window scaling is just a function of the socket receive buffer size. What's the purpose here?

Comment: I need to connect to a device which has a broken implementation of TCP window scaling.

Comment: I guess it would just be annoying to suggest 'fix the device with the broken stack'?

Comment: @MartinJames: That would be great, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: So you just need to ensure that you don't advertise a receive buffer > 64k.

Comment: @EJP: Is it guaranteed that if the receive buffer does not exceed 64K, the kernel will not enable window scaling for that connection? Can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. There are no per-process APIs for sockets at all, just per-socket APIs and global kernel configurations.

But you don't need to modify the scale settings directly. You just need to set the socket receive buffer size you want *prior to connecting.* Then the appropriate window scale is negotiated during the connect handshake. If you want *mo* window scaling! make sure your socket receive buffer is < 64k before connecting. In the case of accepted sockets, that is set on the listening socket.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I need. I need to modify the scale settings directly, as my question clearly states.

Comment: _"as my question clearly states"_ - most people actually ask the wrong question. Put your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831686/can-i-disable-tcp-windows-scaling-for-a-single-application#comment29493469_19831686) in your question.